# Displaying an attribute name in the print composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm using QGIS 3.16 Hannover and I've got a vector layer of provinces with animal species names as attributes. If the species has been detected in the province, the value of the attribute is `X`; if there are breeding records, the value is `R`; otherwise the value is `NULL`.

I'm producing a map for each species and I'm using the categorized layer style for displaying the provinces where the species is present. Is there a way of automatically display the selected attribute name (*i.e*. the species) in the print composer?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that **Atlas** feature is what you seeking for (see [Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html#generate-an-atlas)). For this case I have a workaround with *Atlas*. Trick is that instead of iterating through geometries I use list of former field names (species names):

1. Create `.csv` with field names in one column and load it into QGIS
   [image]
2. Set this csv layer as *Covarage layer* in *Atlas* settings (layout window) and as *Page name* choose the column with the species names.
   [image]

   The *Page name* will be used to identify the atlas page, and also its values can be referenced in expressions using the `@atlas_pagename` variable. You now have the *Atlas* set up that will generate one page for each species name.
3. Set the polygon layer symbology - as *Value* for categorized symbology use this expression:
   `attribute(@atlas_pagename)`

   The `attribute()` expression returns value of attribute of given field name (i.e. `attribute('species_1')` returns the same result as when you directly select the attribute `species_1`). However, we need this value to change (`species_1`, `species_2` etc.) according to the page of the atlas. Thus we have to use `@atlas_pagename` variable which returns value of page name of current atlas feature. This causes iteration through the fields of the polygon layer because their names are identical to those in the *Page name* of the *Covarage layer* (csv table) used in atlas.

   Now you have to manually add the two categories and set their symbols (other solution is use of *Rule-based* symbology with expression such as `attribute(@atlas_pagename) = 'X'` and so on)

[image]

4. Prepare your layout. For displaying the species name just add text (*Add Label*) and select the name of the field with species names.

[image]

Preview the result:

[image]

Comment: Your solution really works, but I can't actually understand WHY does it work. Could you please explain the process underneath step 3?

Comment: @JesúsPinilla Of course, sorry I was focused on writing the solution and missed some details (also in step 2). Also use of `$currentfeature` in expression is unnecessary in this case. Hope, it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 6):

One option can be create a new project variable, in the Variables tab of the Project Properties menu. And store in the value of that variable the name of the field to apply the symbology.

For example, you can create a new variable named *project_symbology_field* and store the value *Taeniopygia castanotis*.

At the symbology of the layer, the value must be the expression:
`eval( @project_symbology_field)`

At the title of the legend, or in a text item or where you want the name of the field, you can use the expression:
`@project_symbology_field`

To change the field to symbolize, you need to update the value of the variable with other field name.

You can also use some categories instead of the field names, and use a expression like:

```
CASE
  WHEN @proyect_symbology_field = 1 THEN "Taeniopygia castanotis"
  WHEN @proyect_symbology_field = 2 THEN "Other field name"
END
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I think it doesn't make much a difference than typing the species' name manually in each map, unless I'm missing something.